# Checking if deserialized value is null

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
 Console.WriteLine("Deserilizing FolkbokföringsPost");
 var myPersons = Deserialize<List<FolkbokforingspostTYPE>>()
     .Select(x => new Person
     {
          PersonalIdentityNumber = x.Personpost.PersonId.PersonNr,
          SpecialIdentityNumber = x.Personpost.PersonId.Tilltalsnamnsmarkering != null ? x.Personpost.PersonId.Tilltalsnamnsmarkering : null,
          LastName = x.Personpost.Namn.Efternamn != null ? x.Personpost.Namn.Efternamn : null,
          FirstName = x.Personpost.Namn.Fornamn != null ? x.Personpost.Namn.Fornamn : null,
          NationalRegistrationCountyCode = x.Personpost.Folkbokforing.LanKod != null ? x.Personpost.Folkbokforing.LanKod : null,
          NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode = x.Personpost.Folkbokforing.KommunKod != null ? x.Personpost.Folkbokforing.KommunKod : null,
          ForeignDistrubtionAddress1 = x.Personpost.Adresser.Utlandsadress != null ? x.Personpost.Adresser.Utlandsadress.Utdelningsadress1 : null,
          ForeignDistrubtionAddress2 = x.Personpost.Adresser.Utlandsadress != null ? x.Personpost.Adresser.Utlandsadress.Utdelningsadress2 : null,
          ForeignDistrubtionAddress3 = x.Personpost.Adresser.Utlandsadress != null ? x.Personpost.Adresser.Utlandsadress.Utdelningsadress3 : null,
          NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress1 = x.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress != null ? x.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress.Utdelningsadress1 : null,
          NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2 = x.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress != null ? x.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress.Utdelningsadress2 : null,
          NationalRegistrationPostCode = x.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress != null ? x.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress.PostNr : null,
          UnregistrationReason = x.Personpost.Avregistrering != null ? x.Personpost.Avregistrering.AvregistreringsorsakKod : null,
          UnregistrationDate = x.Personpost.Avregistrering != null ? x.Personpost.Avregistrering.Avregistreringsdatum : null,
          NationalRegistrationCity = x.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress != null ? x.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress.Postort : null,
          NationalRegistrationDate = x.Personpost.Folkbokforing != null ? x.Personpost.Folkbokforing.Folkbokforingsdatum : null,

          if(x.Personpost.Fodelse.OrtUtlandet != null) //<-- The name 'x' does not exist in the current context
          {
               ForeignBirthCity = x.Personpost.Fodelse.OrtUtlandet != null ? x.Personpost.Fodelse.OrtUtlandet.FodelseortUtland : null, //<-- The name 'ForeignBirthCity' does not exist in the current context
          }

          ProtectedIdentity = x.Sekretessmarkering != null ? x.Sekretessmarkering : null, //<-- The name 'ProtectedIdentity' does not exist in the current context
          CitizenshipCode = x.Personpost.Medborgarskap.MedborgarskapslandKod != null ? x.Personpost.Medborgarskap.MedborgarskapslandKod : null //<-- The name 'CitizenshipCode' does not exist in the current context
     });
```

I get these errors:

> //<-- The name 'CitizenshipCode' does not exist in the current context
>
> //<-- The name 'ProtectedIdentity' does not exist in the current
>   context
>
> //<-- The name 'ForeignBirthCity' does not exist in the current
>   context
>
> //<-- The name 'x' does not exist in the current context

Why do I get these errors and how can I fix it?

Comment: Would be helpful to see the code of class `FolkbokforingspostTYPE`

Comment: You can't write `if` statement in your `Select()` code!

Answer (score 0):

Just delete if statement from you code, It doesn't make sense because of

```
ForeignBirthCity = x.Personpost.Fodelse.OrtUtlandet != null ? x.Personpost.Fodelse.OrtUtlandet.FodelseortUtland : null,
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your target object of type **FolkbokforingspostTYPE** have the **List** type object to deserialize it.

It should be like :

```
 public class FolkbokforingspostTYPE
 {
  public List<Person> Person{get;set;}
 }
```

and Your Person class have the following properties as well:

```
public class Person
 {
    CitizenshipCode
    ProtectedIdentity
    CitizenshipCode
 }
```

And your deserialization should be like this:

```
var obj= new List<FolkbokforingspostTYPE>(){
//intialize your object
}
var myPersons = Deserialize<List<FolkbokforingspostTYPE>>(obj);
```